# Java ProcessBuilder - run command/bat File as Administrator

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm using a third-party software (MFT) in my program, which is used for updating and receiving information from Network Cards.

In order to get information, I need to use the command `mst status` which requires Admin privileges.

So far, I've been using ProcessBuilder to execute commands directly out of my software. However, when my programm reaches this command, I just get "Only administrators can get the devices list" as answer.

I've tried creating a .bat-File, and then creating a shortcut to it, selecting "Run as Administrator" in its properties. However, with this approach the software returns `""` as result.
Through so manual testing with the files themselves, I figured out that the shortcut never returns anything, and if I start the bat File without using the shortcut, I get the old "Only administrators..." again

Is there any other way I could execute this command with Administrator Privileges?

Comment: Use `runas` *in* the batch file?

Comment: @g00se I experimented around a bit with this idea, but the problem here seems to be, that the batch file then asks for a password. How would I be able to tell Java to enter the password, and going further, if I were to execute this software on a different PC, how would it know the Administrators password?

Comment: Yes that would be tricky. They might not even know it themselves ;) But if your 'theory' is that it's simpler to rely on UAC, then couldn't they just right-click your app and 'Run as administrator'?

Comment: @g00se honestly, I'm just testing if that will work right now and if it does this will likely be the workaround I'll have to accept. Been sitting on this for a week, it seems there is just no easy way to run a single command with administrator privileges. All search results either redirect me to the "runAs" command, or some variation of that in powershell, which also doesn't seem to work.
Really leaves me wondering, is this such a rare use case? Why is there no option for ProcessBuilder to execute commands as Administrator, or something like that?

Comment: @g00se also, this program is supposed to do a lengthy setup of some servers. If one of my co-workers forgets to run it as admin (which is likely to happen) the setup will fail for this specific part and they'll either have to fix it manually, or start the whole setup again.. Which is why I was desparate for a solution other than "Run as Administrator"

Comment: It's really not a Java problem. Not really even an OS problem, as you'd have exactly the same issues on Unix, where you'd have to run it as root one way another, the only difference being that Unixes have a more rational, historic and smoother way of elevating process privilege